# Spring locale default lang properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it posssible to set default language in spring? For example I've locale "ru" or "us" but I don't have files such like: lang_us.properties and lang_ru.properties in my spring project instead of this I have only lang_en.properties. And now is it possible to set lang file to lang_en when lang_ru or lang_us file not found in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System take the language of the computer or if the file dosen'T exist it takes always the file for english. I hoped i have helped you :)